# Оптимальный шаблон проектирования для GUI. WPF

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование

Есть небольшое приложение на WPF, еще на стадии готовки:)
Часть GUI уже готово. Когда делал, не думал про шаблоны, но начал думать про старость и как себе ее облегчить. Сейчас работает все так: Есть окна, и в их обьектах их классов хранятся обекты для их работы(временные переменные, постоянные, вся логика тоже в них). Под какой шаблон лучше подгонять проект? (с точки зрения трудоемкости и будущего удобства)
 Я рассматриваю mvc, mvp, mvvm. Возможно какой-то из этих трех вообще не паттерн для десткопного GUI и я снес жуткую чушь. Буду рад выслушать советы.

Comment: Не совсем ясен вопрос. WPF он уже заточен под шаблон MVVM.

Comment: @Carma: как ни странно, MVVM появился _после_ WPF и был придуман не в Майкрософт :) На самом деле, это адаптация старого доброго MVC.

Answer (score 4):

Все паттерны очень абстрактны и носят рекомендательный характер. Каждое приложеие уникально и при проектировке сложно учесть все моменты, тем более их расширение. Поэтому Все паттерны которые ты указал служат только скелетами для программы.
Для WPF надо использовать MVVM. Вынеси объекты модели (смотри [пример](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99330/WPF-Step-by-Step-Getting-Started-with-WPF-and-Expr), очень полезный). Далее Если в обработчиках событий будет что-то сложное или объемное, например алгоритмы, иерархия классов, переключения состояний, ограничения и др, т.е. появится какая-то бизнес логика, то это верный признал того, что надо использовать дополнительные новые [шаблоны](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) в твоем приложении. Советую почитать, или хотя бы посмотреть [книгу](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/). Какие именно - надо разбираться что будет делать твое приложение, как оно будет расширяться. Главное не переусердствовать, смотри [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/153225/)

Comment: +1, MVVM -- путь истинного джедая.